# How to set a video background in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I need to make a background app in the form of a video. But through CSS, you can only add an image. Can you tell me how to add a video?

I wanted to try to specify just the URL of that video, but as expected it was useless.

Comment: [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) are only *based* on CSS (version 2.1), they don't support their full specification.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it alone using qt designer. you have to do it using one of the programming language like python or c++.